# CSS on the text isn't working

Tags: css, css-float

I have a CSS error that i cannot seem to solve with margin or padding. Probably a quick fix, just need someone to look at it

The problem is with the text that appears down and to the right side, which is enclosed in a single `font` tag.

[Page with fault](http://cardpaymentmachines.com/form2.php)

[CSS for that page](http://cardpaymentmachines.com/css2/style.css)

Comment: and what exactly isn't working?

Comment: Where would you expect it to be? The form doesn't fit within its border.

Comment: there is no height on the border anyway...

Comment: look i have put a height on for your purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***hint*** : do not use `font` tag .. [it is deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#h-15.2.2)

Add to the `#form` css rule `overflow:hidden`.
Also to the `font` tag (*or the `span` you will use instead*), add `float:left` and `clear:both` as well as the margins/paddings you want.

Read http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-floats-101/ and http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/ to learn how floated elements work.

Comment: @user1867259,  then you could upvote and/or accept my answer.. Read http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: it won't let me due to reputation